# В чем разница между XPathNavigator и XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

В чем разница между XPathNavigator и XmlDocument?

Вроде бы методы похожи.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135897/xpathdocument-vs-xmldocument

Comment: @Ev_Hyper Так дерзайте. Переведите ответы, получите репутации. потом ещё поисследуете, дополните, вообще будет клондайк.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, спасибо, но нет. Т.к. на написание нормального ответ уйдет больше времени, чем то, которым сейчас располагаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если говорить в общем, то `XmlDocument` предоставляет объектно-ориентированный метод обработки *XML*, тогда как `XPathNavigator` - курсор-ориентированный метод работы.

Практически же разница заключается в том, что `XPathNavigator` более прост и быстр, но `XmlDocument` более гибок. Например, если Вам нужно создать новый *XML* документ, то Вам придется использовать `XmlDocument`, так как `XPathNavigator` (вернее, `XPathDocument`) требует уже созданного документа.

Рекомендуется применять классы `XPathDocument` и `XPathNavigator` при работе с очень большими *XML* документами в силу того, что они немного быстрее. Во всех остальных случаях, `XmlDocument` выглядит предпочтительнее.

Comment: Т.е XPathDocument не грузит документ целиком в память?

Comment: И еще вопрос, а в чем тогда отличие от XmlReader? Он же тоже вроде, как курсор и читает все последовательно.

Comment: Не совсем так: грузить-то он грузит (но на 100% не скажу, не смотрел исходники), но при этом совершается (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.xml/System/Xml/XPath/XPathDocument.cs,024a72e2f976aed9) задействуется меньше вызовов, чем при загрузке XmlDocument-а.

Comment: XmlReader (см. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReader.cs ) это класс уровня абстракции ниже, нежели чем XPathDocument, то есть он еще проще и быстрее, но и уровень предоставляемого сервиса ниже.

Comment: Прошу прощения, в первом комментарии фразу "не смотрел исходники" нужно зачеркнуть. Из-за странной политики редактирования ru.so не могу внести исправления :( 
Да, и исходники смотреть можно и нужно!